# PayPal shopping cart variables – custom variables

Tags: php, paypal

I am currently using `item_name_`, 'amount_`and`quantity_` in a PayPal shopping cart form (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#shopping-cart-variables) but I also need to pass some custom variables (download url and format, specific to my shop) but it doesn't seem to allow such things?

Has anyone got any experience of this? Is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can send custom variables the following way:

option_name1 = "MyVariableName"
option_selection1 = "Whatever value you want"

option_name2 = "MyVariableName2"
option_selection2 = "Whatever value you want 2"

Be warned that since **today** PayPal will add _1 to the returned IPN parameter keys.
So the IPN response will look like this: option_name1_1 = "MyVariableName" and option_selection1_1
I just had this very problem and had to fix em like this:

```
$pattern =[
        "/^(option_(?:name|selection)\d)_\d$/",
        "/^(item_name)\d$/",
        "/^(item_number)\d$/",
    ];
foreach ($ipn_post_data as $key=>$value){
    $ipn_post_data[preg_replace($pattern, "\\1", $key, -1 )] = $value;
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EAB0105Z